# Node.js - Kак узнать о том, что в приложении происходит блокировка потока?

Tags: node.js

Хочу написать модуль, который выводит в консоль сообщение о том, что в приложении произошла блокировка на какой-то промежуток времени.

Kак узнать о том, что в приложении происходит блокировка потока?

Comment: Нода позволяет получать информацию о синхронных вызовах с помощью аргумента --trace-sync-io.